# Removing the "File Browser Tab" for certain roles

Tags: 7

How would I go about removing the "File Browser Tab" from the user profile page for certain roles?

I only want authors, editors and administrators to be able to browse through and upload the files.

Comment: `hook_menu` in a custom module. `if (does't_have_role) { $items['user/%user/imce'] = NULL; }`

Comment: Thank you @AdamBalsam
Where do I need to paste this code?

Comment: Is it possible to hide the tab via permissions? I am using drupal 7

Answer (score 1):

No need to do any coding. We can do it through admin dashboard itself.

Just go to below link:

> /admin/config/media/imce

Under "Role-profile assignments" just choose "Public Files" as NONE against a user role to whome you don't want to show the "File Browser".